# How to avoid groovy code in GSP?

Tags: grails, gsp

I've to display check box checked or not based on some logic which is more than 4 lines of groovy code ...
I don't like to write  it in GSP page..is there any taglib or some way I can extract the logic out of GSP page.
where I could access model boject and request objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) 3 options:

**Model attribute**

If you're only doing the complex logic for a single page or a single controller, do the logic in the controller method and pass the boolean result to the view through a boolean:

```
// in your controller
def myAction() {
    [shouldDrawCheckbox: shouldDrawCheckBox(...)]
}

private boolean shouldDrawCheckBox(/* info for decision making */) {
    // decision making
}
```

**Service method**

If you're going to access this identical logic from several controllers, you can extract the `shouldDrawCheckBox` method into a service and again pass the result through the models.

```
class MyController {
    def myService

    def myAction() {
        [shouldDrawCheckbox: myService.shouldDrawCheckbox(...)]
    }
}

class MyService {
    boolean shouldDrawCheckBox(...) {
        // logic!
    }
}
```

**Custom Taglib**

If you want to avoid passing the decision through the model, or if the logic is more generally applicable, you can create a custom taglib.

```
class MyTaglib {
    static namespace = "my"

    def myCheckbox = { attrs ->
        // extract decision info from the attrs
        // perform logic with info
        if (shouldDrawCheckbox)
            out << g.checkbox(attrs: attrs)
        }
    }
}
```

In your view:

```
<my:myCheckbox whateverYourAttribsAre="value" name="..." value="..."/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A TagLib is a good palce to put your logic, you can pass what you need as attributes and do your test:

```
class MyTagLib {
  static namespace = "my"

  def somecheckbox= { attrs ->
      def model = attrs.remove('model')
      if() { //tests goes here
          //you can also test if you need to mark the checkbox as checked
          if() {
              attrs.checked = "checked"
          }
          out << g.checkbox(attrs: attrs) //remaining attrs will be applied to the checkbox
      }
  }

}
```

**myview.gsp**

```
<my:somecheckbox model="${model}" name="checkboxname" value="${checkboxValue}" />
```

Comment: Out of my curiosity, is it necessary to create a taglib for a logic around a checkbox which will be used in only one gsp? @Sergio: I would appreciate your opinion on this.

Comment: @dmahapatro I think that depends on how complex is your logic. If it is just a flag to show or not, and you will not reuse this, you can do in your controller, but a TagLib is a good place because you have full control of the attributes that will go to the checkbox, and can easily change the html generated.

Comment: I think one of the major advantages to moving the logic into a tag lib is that you can now write unit tests for that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the logic should go to the controller which `renders` the gsp and sets a flag in the `model` object. If the gsp is a child of a template, then the flag has to pass through. DOM manipulations in view layer is not ideal when we have appropriate binding framework available in grails.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `g:` namespace. http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Tags/checkBox.html

```
<g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" value="${condition}" />
```

It doesn't get any simpler then this. All the logic should be done inside the controller.

All the data you need on a page can be passed by the controller. Just return a `Map`.

```
class MyController {
    def index() {
        def someCondition = true
        [request:request, condition:someCondition]
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the `value` of the checkbox be dynamically handled by the "4 lines of Groovy code" mentioned earlier in the above sample code? Appreciate your explanation in advance.

Comment: Do the handling in the controller and pass the boolean value to the checkbox tag.

Comment: That is exactly what I tried to `edit` in your answer earlier which was not accepted, I guess. Thanks for the latest edit which makes the sample code lucid about the usage `condition`.

Comment: Sorry, I did see a message about an edit but didn't how to accept :-)